# Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:classpath'.Could not find com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5

Tags: android, android-studio, gson, expo, react-native

Am working on React native expo project. I updated my expo SDK 33 to 42 and tried to run my App with Android but I got an error.

`Failed to apply plugin[id 'kotlin-android'] The Current Gradle Version 4.10.2 is not compatible with the kotlin Gradle plugin. Please use gradle 5.3 or new`

so I updated my Gradle with`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.3-all.zip`  and now I got more errors.

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
```

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:classpath'.
> Could not find com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.5/gson-2.8.5.pom
> If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
> Required by:
> project :app > com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10
> project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.3.0 > com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-buildtools:2.3.0
> Could not find com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-jre.
> Searched in the following locations:

I don't know what I missed.